# Automated Apps Script for BigQuery Failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I keep getting this error

> "ReferenceError: "BigQuery" is not defined. (line 19, file "Code")"

when trying to this script in apps script

```
function saveQueryToTable() {
  var projectId = 'fiery-cabinet-****';
  var datasetId = '11234***1';
  var tableId = 'TEST4';
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT *' +
               'FROM Test2;',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Could anyone let me know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to enable the BigQuery service.

1. Resources > Advanced Google Services
2. Enable BigQuery

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Graham Polley. I'm getting further now but it's trying to connect with a random project (not the one specified in the code and I get this response "Project 603804914871 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. (line 19, file "Code")" any ideas?

Comment: i'll create a new question as it's slightly different

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and couldn't find it at first since the layout changed a lot since 2017.

If you need to do this in 2021, from Apps Script UI:

1. Editor (< >)
2. Services ("+" sign)
3. Select BigQuery API
4. Add

And that's it!

PS: Google documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

Answer (score -1):

If you are under Google Apps Script UI, you can reach the "Advanced Google Services" under Resources.

Happy coding!