# how to access bigquery data from firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

Is it posssible to access bigquery data from firebase cloud functions?
or can we write a cloud function which can perform operation directly of bigquery data?

**Update:**
This is MyCode

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');


const admin = require('firebase-admin');


var serviceAccount = require("");


admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendBigQueryData = functions.analytics.event('app_open').onLog(event => {


var bigQuery = BigQuery({ projectId:  });
    bigQuery.query({


        query: 'SELECT CAST(TIMESTAMP_ADD(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros), INTERVAL 330 MINUTE) AS date) AS event_date, count(event.name) AS number_questions FROM ``, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event WHERE event.name="asked_question" GROUP BY event_date ORDER BY event_date DESC'
    }).then(function (results) {


        var ref = admin.database().ref('');

        var rows = results[0]; //get all fetched table rows
        rows.forEach(function(row){ //iterate through each row
            ref.push().set({ //write to the database, under the 'queryresults' node
                column1:row['col1'],
                column2:row['col2']
            });
        });
        //return result
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //return an error
    })
  });
```

**ReferenceError: BigQuery is not defined**

```
at exports.sendBigQueryData.functions.analytics.event.onLog.event (/user_code/index.js:11:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
at next (native)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71
at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:53:36)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:695:26
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Comment: You should run `npm install --save @google-cloud/bigquery` on your project directory

Comment: npm install --save @google-cloud/bigquery
already tried this also!

Comment: Did you run it with administrative privileges?

Comment: yes have admin privileges for this project under which i m running this function

Comment: Check this [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42974126/5861618)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to acess bigquery data from a Cloud Function. You simply need to import it using `require()`:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
```

**Edit**: If your cloud function doesn't have a realtime database trigger, you'll need to add the Admin SDK as well in order to write to the database:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Then run the query inside your declared cloud function:

```
var bigQuery = BigQuery({ projectId: 'YOUR-PROJECT-ID' });
    bigQuery.query({
        query: 'YOUR QUERY HERE'
    }).then(function (results) {
        var ref = admin.database().ref('queryresults');

        var rows = results[0]; //get all fetched table rows
        rows.forEach(function(row){ //iterate through each row
            ref.push().set({ //write to the database, under the 'queryresults' node
                column1:row['col1'],
                column2:row['col2']
            });
        });
        //return result
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //return an error
    });
```

Comment: and if i want to store this query result to my realtime database then???

Comment: i have tried the below code but facing the below error! help in resolving this error please

Comment: I've removed the parenthesis after the BigQuery import. Please check

Comment: i have also removed but the same error is coming.
error is coming on
BigQuery is not defined at exports.sendBigQueryData.functions.analytics.event.onLog.event

Answer (score 2):

[Examples I've seen](https://blog.questionable.services/article/from-firestore-to-bigquery-firebase-functions/) require BigQuery to be instantiated like this:

Change this line:

```
var bigQuery = BigQuery({ projectId:  });
```

to this:

```
var bigQuery = new BigQuery({ projectId:  });
```